# PHP: parse URL for matching directory /somedirectory/ and execute conditional code

Tags: php, wordpress, url

This has to be pretty simple, but I'd like to parse the current URL and execute conditional code depending on whether the user is on the */sitemap/* directory.

So for example, if the site is *example.com*, and if the request is *example.com/sitemap/*.

Then I want to execute conditional code in that case. I'm using wordpress so I'm not sure if there is a built-in function that gets this...

A pure PHP solution is fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don’t know if Wordpress has some function for that. But you could do this:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_PATH'] = preg_replace('/\\?.*/', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` contains the URI path plus the query and the code above will just get the URI path. Then you can compare it to your string:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_PATH'] == '/sitemap/') {
    // URI path is "/sitemap/"
}
```

Or you do a *starts with* test:

```
$start = '/sitemap/';
if (substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_PATH'], 0, strlen($start)) == $start) {
    // URI path starts with "/sitemap/"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

And you run phpinfo() in a simple script, you will see EVERYTHING you might want to get your hands on from pure PHP. (and a lot of other stuff too, just scroll to the bottom of the output for PHP variables.)

Comment: While a round-a-bout answer, I was thinking of suggesting the same thing.  I'm glad you threw it out there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use build-in web server variables for this. Here are some example:

- `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` - host name for current request
- `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` - requested url with get parameters

You can also see full list by `print_r($_SERVER);`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$paths = explode ('/', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

This will give you an array of paths for the given script.  You can perform logic based on the resulting array.

Comment: Note:  PHP_SELF is the "web path" where as PATH_TRANSLATED is the "file system path"

Answer (score 0):

```
current( explode( '/', trim( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/' ) ) )
```

will return the first part of the url

```
explode( '/', trim( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/' ) )
```

will create an array of the url parts

Answer (score 0):

With the following line of PHP code you will get the URL of the HTTP Request of the current page:

$url = ((preg_match("/(^\z|^off\z)/i", $_SERVER['HTTPS'])) ? 'http://' : 'https://') . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

Then you may want to parse this URL to get a reliable result array like this:

- [SCHEME] => http
- [AUTHORITY] => user:pass@www.domain.com:80
- [USERINFO] => user:pass
- [USER] => user
- [PASS] => pass
- [HOST] => www.domain.com
- [REGNAME] => www.domain.com
- [DOMAIN] => www.domain.com
- [LABEL][] =>
- [LABEL][] => com
- [LABEL][] => domain
- [LABEL][] => www
- [PORT] => 80
- [PATH] => /dir1/dir2/dir3/page.html
- [SEGMENT][] => dir1
- [SEGMENT][] => dir2
- [SEGMENT][] => dir3
- [SEGMENT][] => page.html
- [QUERY] => key1=value1&key2=value2
- [GET][key1] => value1
- [GET][key2] => value2
- [FRAGMENT] => anchor/line
- [ANCHOR][] => anchor
- [ANCHOR][] => line

There's a standard-compliant, robust and performant PHP Class for handling and parsing URLs / URIs according to RFC 3986 and RFC 3987 available for download and free use:

http://andreas-hahn.com/en/parse-url